# Inserting design elements in my WordPress nav menu

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Hi to everyone and many thanks to all who put out the effort to help me.

Here is my problem, and please bear with me as I'm relatively new to all of this.

I'm trying create a custom WordPress theme for the blog on my site, so that the look and feel of my blog and my site are seamless.

Right now my problem is the nav menu. I have vertical lines separating the nav links and I have been unable to find any examples that show how to do this, or something like it in WordPress and if it's possible can it be done without jQuery.

Here is my site for the visual; http://is-images.com/

If it helps, here is the html code for the menu and the css

```
<div id="HeaderNav">
                <ul>
                    <li class="link"><a href="/" class="nav about">about</a></li>
                    <li class="navsep">&nbsp;</li>
                    <li class="link"><a href="web.php" class="nav web">web</a></li>
                    <li class="navsep">&nbsp;</li>
                    <li class="link"><a href="photo.php" class="nav photo">photo</a></li>
                    <li class="navsep">&nbsp;</li>
                    <li class="link"><a href="#" class="nav blog">blog</a></li>
                    <li class="navsep">&nbsp;</li>
                    <li class="link"><a href="contact.php" class="nav contact">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
#HeaderNav
{
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    height:24px;
    float:right;
    margin-top:70px;
    margin-right:37px;
}

#HeaderNav ul
{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    float:right;
}

#HeaderNav ul li
{
    padding:0 4px;
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}

#HeaderNav ul li.navsep
{
    width:1px;
    height:24px;
    margin:0 7px;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

If anyone can help, in any way, I would greatly appreciate it.

Again, many thanks to all who put out the effort.

Comment: do you already added it as  your wordpress menu or you expecting help for that too. or do you need help only  for css fixing ??

Comment: I just needed help with the CSS, the rest I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add vertical lines to separate your nav menu options on your wordpress theme you can do it with a few CSS rules. jQuery is not needed.

Here you go:

```
li.menu-item a {
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, why I didn't think of that I don't know as it's so obvious. I've modified it a little, instead of li.menu-item a, I use li.menu-item. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

they have just create an empty element after each menu:

```
<li class="navsep">&nbsp;</li>
```

Then design it with css

```
#HeaderNav ul li.navsep
{
  width:1px;
  height:24px;
  margin:0 7px;
  padding:0;
  background-color:#ffffff;
}
```